# lighting in OpenGL with shaders

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to apply some lighting to texture.
I have created a textured cube and I placed a camera inside of it.
Now, I'd like to light its internal faces. I've been told I should use shaders, so I read many tutorials and I've created:

**vertex shader:**

```
const GLchar* vertexSkySource =
#if defined(__APPLE_CC__)
"#version 150 core\n"
#else
"#version 130\n"
#endif
"uniform mat3 view_rot;"
"in vec3 position;"
"out vec3 Coord;"
"void main() {"
"   Coord = view_rot * position;"
"   gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);"
"}";
```

**fragment shader**

```
const GLchar* fragmentSkySource =
#if defined(__APPLE_CC__)
"#version 150 core\n"
#else
"#version 130\n"
#endif
"in vec3 Coord;"
"out vec4 outColor;"
"uniform samplerCube textureSampler;"
"void main() {"
"   outColor =  texture(textureSampler, Coord);"
"}";
```

After I initialize them

```
void initialize_shader()
{
    // shader per la skybox
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSkySource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    {
        GLchar log[512];
        GLsizei slen = 0;
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, &slen, log);
        if (slen)
            std::cerr << log << std::endl;
    }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSkySource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    {
        GLchar log[512];
        GLsizei slen = 0;
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, &slen, log);
        if (slen)
            std::cerr << log << std::endl;
    }

    skyProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(skyProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(skyProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(skyProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(skyProgram);
    GLint status = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(skyProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (!status)
    {
        std::cout << "failed to link" << std::endl;
        GLchar log[256];
        GLsizei slen = 0;
        glGetProgramInfoLog(skyProgram, 256, &slen, log);
        std::cout << log << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}
```

Then in my draw method which will be called inside `main` method I do this:

```
glm::vec3 light_direction = glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.f, 1.f, 3.f));
glm::vec3 light_position = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec3 light_intensity = glm::vec3(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);

glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glUseProgram(skyProgram);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureCube);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(skyProgram, "textureSampler"), 3);
glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(skyProgram, "light_direction"), 1, &light_direction[0]);
glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(skyProgram, "light_intensity"), 1, &light_intensity[0]);
glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(skyProgram, "view_position"), 1, &camera_position[0]);
glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(skyProgram, "shininess"), 60); // shininess = 60, range is [0.0 - 128.0] 
glUniformMatrix3fv(glGetUniformLocation(skyProgram, "view_rot"), 1, GL_FALSE, &(glm::mat3(glm::inverse(view)))[0][0]);
```

I can't see lights on the cube faces, what should I add to my shaders?

Comment: From what I see, you are nowhere calculating any lighting in the shader. And you are getting OpenGL errors for sure, since you are trying to set uniforms that are not present in the shader.

Comment: @BDL: actually, setting uniforms with location -1 is explicitely not generating an error in GL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending light parameters (`light_direction`, `light_intensity`, `view_position` and `shininess`) into the shader, but you're not receiving them or doing anything with them. Your fragment shader only reads a texture but doesn't apply any lighting to it:

```
outColor =  texture(textureSampler, Coord);
```

Complete source to shading would be big and without seeing more code is hard to give, so I'll give some pointers:

- The first thing would be adding some `glGetError()` calls into various parts of your C++ code so you'll know if you use OpenGL API wrong.
- In addition to position, you'll need to send vertex normals to the shader
- You'll need to choose a shading algorithm, [Blinn-Phong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model) is simple and widely used.
- You'll need to make sure that normal and light direction are in the same coordinate-space

So, in the end your `outColor` needs to be multiplied with the calculated shading:

```
outColor =  texture(textureSampler, Coord) * shading;
```

but you'll need to modify your vertex and fragment shader to calculate it based on the light's direction and vertex normal.

**Edit** based on [GitHub project](https://github.com/luca92c/openGL):

I compiled and ran the project and had to fix some problems:

- Include and Library paths were set for your computer and not relative to the project directory.
- In the fragment shader you are declaring "shading" as "out". Remove that line and add `vec4 shading = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` before `shading += vec4...`
- `vec4(light_intensity)` is wrong and doesn't compile on my NVIDIA Windows driver, replace with `vec4(light_intensity,1.0)`

I couldn't get anything on the screen even if I modified the shader to always output red.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I modified the code but I'm really struggling to understand/make the shading works. I've uploaded my entire code here: https://github.com/luca92c/openGL . I don't know how far I am from obtaining a simple Phong shading effect, this is my first openGL project..

Comment: Thank you, again. Now I can see the light effect. However, can you explain me what do the 4 parameters in vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); mean?

Comment: @splunk red, green, blue and alpha. Shading starts at zero and each light contributes to the final shading (the `+=` in your code).

Comment: last question. What if I would add a direction to the shading? How do I go about?

Comment: @splunk Do you mean adding another light?